# copying content from one document library to another

Tags: powershell

I am copying the contents from one library to another in SharePoint 2010 using powershell.
I am new to powershell, so far I am able to get the files name and url using :

```
    Get-SPWeb http://sitecollection/sites/site/subsite |
    Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
    Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary" -and
            $_.Title -eq "test" } |
    Select -ExpandProperty Items |
    Select Name, url
```

Can anyone help me on this front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script I [found](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Copy-all-SharePoint-Files-0999c53f)

```
$ver = $host | select version 
if($Ver.version.major -gt 1) {$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"} 
if(!(Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0)) 
{ 
Write-Progress -Activity "Loading Modules" -Status "Loading Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
} 

## 
#Set Static Variables 
## 

$SourceWebURL = "http://www.contoso.com" 
$SourceLibraryTitle = "Shared Documents" 
$DestinationWebURL = "http://archive.contoso.com/WWWArchive" 
$DestinationLibraryTitle = "Shared Documents" 

## 
#Begin Script 
## 

$sWeb = Get-SPWeb $SourceWebURL 
$sList = $sWeb.Lists | ? {$_.Title -eq $SourceLibraryTitle} 
$dWeb = Get-SPWeb $DestinationWebURL 
$dList = $dWeb.Lists | ? {$_.title -like $DestinationLibraryTitle} 

$AllFolders = $sList.Folders 
$RootFolder = $sList.RootFolder 
$RootItems = $RootFolder.files 

foreach($RootItem in $RootItems) 
{ 
    $sBytes = $RootItem.OpenBinary() 
    $dFile = $dList.RootFolder.Files.Add($RootItem.Name, $sBytes, $true) 

    $AllFields = $RootItem.Item.Fields | ? {!($_.sealed)} 

    foreach($Field in $AllFields) 
    { 
        if($RootItem.Properties[$Field.Title]) 
        { 
            if(!($dFile.Properties[$Field.title])) 
            { 
                $dFile.AddProperty($Field.Title, $RootItem.Properties[$Field.Title]) 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $dFile.Properties[$Field.Title] = $RootItem.Properties[$Field.Title] 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    $dFile.Update() 
} 

foreach($Folder in $AllFolders) 
{ 
    Remove-Variable ParentFolderURL 
    $i = 0 

    $FolderURL = $Folder.url.Split("/") 

    while($i -lt ($FolderURL.count-1)) 
    { 
    $ParentFolderURL = "$ParentFolderURL/" + $FolderURL[$i] 
    $i++ 
    } 

    $CurrentFolder = $dList.Folders | ? {$_.url -eq $ParentFolderURL.substring(1)} 
    if(!($CurrentFolder.Folders | ? {$_.name -eq $Folder.Name})) 
    { 
        $NewFolder = $dlist.Folders.Add(("$DestinationWebURL" + $ParentFolderURL), [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder, $Folder.name) 
        $NewFolder.update() 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $NewFolder = $dList.Folders | ? {$_.name -eq $Folder.Name} 
    } 
    $AllFiles = $sList.Items 
    $sItems = $Folder.folder.Files 

    if($Folder.Folder.Files.count -gt 0) 
    { 
        foreach($item in $sItems) 
        { 

            $Relative = ($Item.ServerRelativeUrl).substring(1) 
            $TargetItem = $AllFiles | ? {$_.URL -eq $Relative} 
            $sBytes = $TargetItem.File.OpenBinary() 
            $dFile = $Newfolder.Folder.Files.Add($TargetItem.Name, $sBytes, $true) 
            $AllFields = $TargetItem.Fields | ? {!($_.sealed)} 

            foreach($Field in $AllFields) 
            { 
                if($TargetItem.Properties[$Field.Title]) 
                { 
                    if(!($dFile.Properties[$Field.title])) 
                    { 
                        $dFile.AddProperty($Field.Title, $TargetItem.Properties[$Field.Title]) 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        $dFile.Properties[$Field.Title] = $TargetItem.Properties[$Field.Title] 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            $dFile.Update() 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this script is too heavy to execute. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Its not an easy job as you think. You can get the information in one line. But for uploading and copying metadata etc will need more lines of code.